# Programming hangman in java, having troubles concluding game (mostly finished)

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program09
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the phrase to be guessed at: ");
        String cp = stdIn.nextLine();

// I added the 'revealed' variable, and it seemed to help somewhat. 

        char [] tmpArr = new char [cp.length()];
        int spaces = initTemplateArray(cp, tmpArr);
        int cons = 0;
        int vowel = 0;
        int revealed = 0;
        boolean running = true;
        printTemplateArray(tmpArr);

        do
        {
            char c = getConsonant(stdIn);
            cons += updateTemplateArray(tmpArr, cp, c);
            revealed += updateTemplateArray(tmpArr, cp, c);
            printTemplateArray(tmpArr);
            System.out.println();

            if (cons >= 1)
            {
            char v = getVowel(stdIn);
            vowel += updateTemplateArray(tmpArr, cp, v);
            revealed += updateTemplateArray(tmpArr, cp, v);
            printTemplateArray(tmpArr);
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (revealed == tmpArr.length - spaces)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations!\n\nThe phrase contained " + cons + " consonants, " + vowel + " vowels, and " + spaces + " spaces.");
            running = false;
        }
    } while (running);

    stdIn.close();
}

//Most of this method was provided for us by the instructor:

public static int updateTemplateArray (char [] tmpArr, String sPhrase, char guess)
{
    int revealed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; ++i)
    {
        if (sPhrase.charAt(i) == guess)
        {
            tmpArr[i] = guess;
            ++revealed;
        }
    }

    return revealed;
 }
}
```

I am having issues ending the game in the main method and printing the results. The program works occasionally (like when you use the word "hell" as the phrase to be guessed). For other words it will continue to ask for consonants and vowels when the word is revealed (without concluding the game), or it will conclude the game before the word is completely revealed.

I have a suspicion that my error lies in my comparing the number of consonants and vowels in the array to the number of chars in the array with my do/while loop.

I searched for other hangman questions here, and found submissions, but none that seemed to cover this specific issue. Sorry about the length.

Comment: There's a lot of code here.  Try to isolate the problem (you have an idea as to where it might be occurring), and edit your code accordingly.

Comment: Kinda odd that you're using pre-increment (`++space`)

Comment: Yeah we have learned about pre vs. post-incrementing, but in the portions of the code that our instructor provided for us he used pre-increment, so I left it.

Comment: You might want to add comments to places where the code was provided so no one would suggest changing those.

Comment: from just the code posted here, you don't check whether the letters are correct or not.  Also, make sure you take into account repeated letters

Comment: I'll edit and put my updateTemplateArray method back, it checks whether the letters are correct.